# How to define variable position and length of an excel range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image][1]

I'm struggling to define a variable position, variable length range.  I want to apply the following SUMPRODUCT logic.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C:C="EUR")*(F:F<10)*E:E/$H$3*F:F)
```

However, I want to replace the full column ranges with only the rows between where "Heading 2" and "Heading 3" are found in column D.  So C:C would be replaced with C10:C11; F:F would be replaced by F10:F11 etc.  The position of both "Heading 2" and "Heading 3" can change (so the position and length of the range are dynamic) so the range can't be hardcoded.
    How can I alter the formula to only apply the SUMPRODUCT logic to the rows between those headings?

I hope that makes sense, appreciate any help!

EDIT: If anyone is looking for the same sort of thing, I managed to get the correct output using the below formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(C:C, MATCH("Heading 2",D:D,0)):INDEX(C:C, MATCH("Heading 3",D:D,0))="EUR")*(INDEX(F:F, MATCH("Heading 2",D:D,0)):INDEX(F:F, MATCH("Heading 3",D:D,0))<10)*INDEX(E:E, MATCH("Heading 2",D:D,0)):INDEX(E:E, MATCH("Heading 3",D:D,0))/$H$3*INDEX(F:F, MATCH("Heading 2",D:D,0)):INDEX(F:F, MATCH("Heading 3",D:D,0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two easy methods of determining the 'last row' in a column but you need to know what you are looking for.

```
'last row with a number or date in a column
=match(1e99, F:F)
'last row with text in a column
=match("zzz", C:C)
```

In a formula where you are trying to restrict the ranges (e.g. SUMPRODUCT), choose one of these and use the defining row for all dynamic ranges. I will assume you have header column labels in row 1 and your data starts in row 2.

All of column C from row 2 to the row in column C that meets the last row with a number in column F.

```
C2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1e99, F:F))
```

Column F is one of the criteria as well as a factor in the resulting sum so no row beyond the last number in column F is valid for any column. Use the row containing the last number in column F as the final row for all columns. This ensures that all valid data is accounted for as well as guaranteeing that all ranges are the same 'size' (i.e. same number of rows). Using one method for column C and another for column F may make the formula invalid due to disproportionate ranges.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1e99, F:F))="EUR")*(F2:INDEX(F:F, MATCH(1e99, F:F))<10)*E2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1e99, F:F))/$H$3*F2:INDEX(F:F, MATCH(1e99, F:F)))
```

The formula is now truly dynamic. As soon as a new number gets input to a fresh row in column F all other ranges will expand accordingly.

Comment: My screenshot was misleading in that the data in column F did not conveniently end at the point where I would like to end the range.  In other words, imagine there were more rows which also had values populated in column F.

However, your proposed logic did get me thinking about how I can set the range more dynamically and I have found the answer (I'll post the logic in my original question)

Thank you for your help!